# How to use lambda to select dates from book table?

Tags: lambda

I have the below function:

```
var filtered_books = book_table.Where<Book>(d => d.CategoryID == Convert.ToInt32(drpCategory.SelectedItem.Value));
lstBooks.DataSource = filtered_books;
lstBooks.DataBind();
```

The error: `An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code.`

Comment: Please edit your question tags to include the language (C#?)

Comment: Did you make sure `drpCategory.SelectedItem` is not null?